# Large number of music files copied from Windows to SD card cannot be seen by music player and looks gone after inserting it

Tags: file-system, music-player

I have a dedicated music player device (TempoTec V6) running a version of Android 8.  I've about 120 GB of music files in MP3 and FLAC format  (which the device supports). I'm baffled about how to get the device to recognize (and not destroy) the SD card holding the files.

I have a 256 and 512 GB SD card formatted in exFAT, copied the music files to them in various ways (never just in the root directory - directory size limitations - but variously to a single subdirectory (called cleverly 'Music') and to about 300 subdirectories of the various artists.  There are ~11000 files.

I've never successfully accessed all the files. The most recent time the card was recognized, but no music files were detected, and when I took the card back out and looked at it in Windows, the card was empty (after 6 hours of writing files and checking the integrity of the file system regularly).

What's going on?  Surely this dedicated music player is going to recognize an SD card...  And I can't see how any device would just wipe the file system of a memory card.

Comment: How old are the SD-cards? Have you ever checked them if they really contain the flash memory they claim to have (there are a lot of fake cards which claim to have e.g. 512GB but actually only have 16 so in the end you overwrite the existing data)? There are special test tools FakeFlashTest or H2Testw which write the whole SD-Card once and then test if all the written data is still consistent.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Could you clarify "*I've never successfully accessed all the files. The most recent time the card was recognized, but no music files detected*"? Did you mean you have also checked the content of the SD card using a file manager app on Android, instead of only from the music player? Also, just in case, have you tried checking the files on the SD card after copying from Windows too?

Comment: Well, are the cards good?  I think so - one was a samsung and the other a Xiaomi so they are not no-name brands.... and they are new.   As I said the last file-copy I did on the PC I separated the files into 6 bunches (so as to copy smaller numbers at a time) and ran a chkdsk after each bunch, no errors reported.  An on Windows the SD card looks as it should after all that - multiple folders and files, ~11000.  However inserted in the android device the file manager system reports only ~3000 files.  Exact same card, 25 seconds apart...   I cannot explain that.

Comment: It really seems like the android is trashing the file system of these big SD cards....   

Is this possible?   I"m old and I've never seen that happen on any of the devices I've used, but these little android devices are new to me....

Comment: Have you tried breaking down the number of files and adding them incrementally while checking the files availability on the music player? I read [a review](https://www.head-fi.org/showcase/tempotec-v6.26011/) mentioning that it needed around 8 minutes to scan around 9200 files for a total of ~256GB files. As for wiping the file system, there was [a recent post with a similar issue on another brand](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251915/44325), though it's corrupting instead of deleting the files.

Comment: The link to the problem with image files on a Samsung phone really sounds very similar - though that was Android 12 and this is v8...      I confess I've not tried the trick of adding additional files incrementally - that would be a bit of a tedious process...   but I guess it would be a possibility.    Still doesn't explain why this happens (nor why the Samsung guy's problems are happening).  I'll get back to this when I get the enthusiasm (I'm somewhat deflated now...)

Comment: **The Xiaomi one IS a fake** - Xiaomi doesn't sell flash memory -: https://xiaomiui.net/dont-buy-worst-fake-xiaomi-products-35694/ . Samsung does but it can be counterfeit as well. Your assumption that "no-name brands" are problematic is simply wrong. A counterfeit product is way more likely to have a (counterfeit) name brand on it, obviously. And it doesn't matter where you bought them, fake SD cards, USB sticks or SSD/HDDs can be found anywhere, including AliExpress and Amazon or even otherwise reputable brick&mortar stores. I strongly suggest you go back to the first comment and test them.

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-fastest-microsd-cards/ (The URL is misleading perhaps on purpose ;) , the article's title is "How to Spot a Fake MicroSD Card and Avoid Being Scammed") It shows all the software tools you can use to test yours. Good luck in getting your money back because there's almost an 100% chance of them being fake.

Comment: OK - (go back to the first comment).  Now I'm really sad - both to have bought 'bad' products and to have taken so much time/space on this list!     I have checked the microSD cards using FakeFlashTest and indeed it seems they are faulty.  So sad!   But a good lesson for me.  Oh well - life is a series of lessons!   Thanks for all your advice.